# Toast not displaying when orientation is changed why..?

Tags: android, layout, orientation, toast

I am showing two different layouts on different orientations.

In both I am Toasting a  message that orientation changed.

It showing in toast in portrait but not in landscape why..?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        System.out.println("Initial Oriatation is "+display.getOrientation());
        int oriatation = display.getOrientation();
        if(oriatation == 0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
            createPort();
            resumePort();
        }else if(oriatation == 1){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
            createLand();
            resumeLand();
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the onConfigurationChanged method which will detect when orientation has been changed.

To make sure that your activity calls this you need to specify android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" in your manifest.

Then in your onConfigurationChanged Method you can have something like:

```
 if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Acording to [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getOrientation%28%29), `Display.getOrientation()` is deprecated, suggesting to use `getRotation()` instead. However, looking at [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface.html#ROTATION_270) for `getRotation()` returned values, I assume that `getOrientation()` might return similar results, so try checking not only for 0 and 1, but for 2 and 3 as well and see what happens.

**edit** instead of `else if(oriatation == 1)` use

```
else if(oriatation % 2 == 1) // or `else if(oriatation == 1 || oriatation == 3)`
```

Comment: previously i printed the values in log cat, to see its values when orientation is chaged.. its giving only 0 and 1.

Comment: getRotation () is from API level 8, but i am developing under API level 7,

Comment: @Noby that's why i didn't suggest using `getRotation()` =) i've actually tried it, `getOrientation()` returned 1 for counter-clockwise 90 degrees and 3 for clockwise 90 degrees.

Comment: i am not getting what i made wrong and whats the solution.. can you please explain me in more detail..?

Answer (score 0):

One strange thing was happening with me when i run this program in android2.3.1(API-9) at first time i get the toast msg that "Changed to Portrait"(i changed the "Changed" to "Changed to Portrait" and "Changed to Landscape".) and when i changes the orientation of screen from Portrait to Landscape i get "Changed to Landscape" but when i again changes the orientation to Portrait the emulator toast the msg "Changed to Landscape" once again.And Now all the time it shows "Changed to Landscape".I googled about the problem and find that when we change the orientation of screen activity loose its initial state and changed to the next state,So we have to hold the initial state of the screen to again see the Toast msg "Changed to Portrait".
There is one class [SharedPrefrences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) who helps us to maintain the state.So try it hope It'll solve ur problem.